# Spring asynchronous thread independent from the application business logic

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

There is a Spring 4.0.6 web application running on glassfish server. I want to run an asynchronous thread independent from the application business logic as soon as the application has been deployed.

The asynchronous thread will run a for loop and for each item will do some modifications in database. The thread will be killed as soon as the modifications has been done for the last item. It should not be a cronjob or task scheduler.

I am new in Spring and any idea would be appriciated.

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: @Palcente: yes, I am using maven.

Comment: I can't remember names off the top of my head, but there are plugins that will allow you to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at @Async & @EnableAsync Annotations of the spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) project.